# Unity3d keep position of player in race game using list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple racing game and I want to keep my player's position and display it . I've thought that it'll be useful to create a list and put inside all my enemies and my player and then sort it but I'm stuck there. For start I've used only one enemy and my player. Here is the code I've done so far. Any ideas how to go on ?

```
public List<GameObject> Balls;
    public Text scoreText;
    int score;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject myPlayer;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject enemy1;

public List<GameObject> Balls;
void myList()
    {
        Balls.Add(myPlayer);
        Balls.Add(enemy1);
        Balls.Sort(CompareDistance);
    }

    private int CompareDistance(GameObject a, GameObject b)
    {
        float distance_a = a.GetComponent<GameObject>().transform.position.z;
        float distance_b = b.GetComponent<GameObject>().transform.position.z;
        if (distance_a >= distance_b)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "keep your player's position"

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to using `Unity3d` and good attempt at this, but do consider using `object-oriented programming` principles. Its good practice.

For example, you can first create a `Participant` class that both your player and enemies will ultimately derive from.

```
public abstract class Participant : MonoBehaviour {
    //By default, the race is along the z direction
    public virtual float GetDistanceTravelled(Vector3 startPoint) {
        return startPoint.z - transform.position.z;
    }

    //At every frame, my participants shall move. How they move depends on what the player and enemy subclasses implement it.
    protected virtual void Update() {
        Move();
    }

    //Your participants will need to move, but players move with keyboard control, while enemies move programmatically. So we let the subclasses implement them.
    protected abstract void Move();
}
```

Now, we create `Player` and `Enemy` scripts and attach them to their respective `GameObjects`.

```
public class Player : Participant {
    public override void Move() {
        //implement how you want to control your player to move
    }
}

public class Enemy : Participant { 
    public override void Move() {
        //implement how the enemies move automatically
    }
}
```

Finally, we need a class `RaceManager` to handle displaying the race details! You can create an empty `GameObject` for this and attach this script there.

```
public class RaceManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<Participant> participants; //you can add participants by dragging the gameobjects here from Unity's inspector, or add them in 
    public Vector3 startPoint; //again, set this in the inspector, or in Start()

    void Start() {
        //You can initialize startPoint, participants here. Or do it in the inspector
    }

    public void GetRaceDetails() {
        //Sort the list first. Check if the list is null first.. I will not do that here for clarity sake
        participants.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.GetDistanceTravelled(startPoint).Value.CompareTo(p2.GetDistanceTravelled(startPoint).Value)); //you can sort easily with lambda expressions

        //print the results here, you can iterate through the list and do a Debug.Log() or something
    }
}
```

Comment: But how am I gonna do this? my movement script for player uses both update and start and var declarations outside of them to make player move , same as enemy, it's gonna be a mess.. sorry I'm newbie in c# ..

Comment: @MariaKodel 1. You can add Start() to the Player class. 2. any examples of such variables used outside? Move them into Player/Participant if it makes sense to do so. 3. Finally, note that Object Oriented Programming is a good principle that applies to many coding languages. Do a Google search to understand how important and widely used it is. It's good to practice this early on when learning how to code :)

Comment: hmm okay so, in update of abstract class I call the corresponding update of player or enemy same as in start function ?

Comment: @MariaKodel if only Player requires Start(), then add it only in Player. Otherwise, if both Enemy and Player require their own Start() functions, add it to Participant as a virtual or abstract function, and then override their implementations in the respective subclasses (Player/Enemy). On a sidenote, if you plan to do programming for the long term (and not just this one time), go look up on what inheritance, polymorphism, composition etc. is, it will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was pretty close but there's simple mistakes. Your results should be the opposite for your sorting function, and GameObject is not a component, is a component container, and you already have the reference. After those two changes your method seems to be working fine. I've also added an equals condition, to avoid swapping elements that don't need swapping.

```
 private int CompareDistance(GameObject a, GameObject b)
    {
        float distance_a = a.transform.position.z;
        float distance_b = b.transform.position.z;
        if (distance_a==distance_b) return 0;
        if (distance_a >= distance_b)
            return -1;  else  return 1;
    }
```

Also try to avoid creating the list too often, create it once and only sort later on,  creating and populating lists can be relatively expensive (as can be sorting)